# Bicep - How to update a dictionary object

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

How to use bicep to update a dictionary object, like:
original dict object:

```bicep
var dict = {
  'a': {}
}
```

I have a array now: ['b', 'c'] and I want to update dict object like:

```bicep
{
  'a': {}
  'b': {}
  'c': {}
}
```

Could I implement this with bicep?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be great if you could explain your use case as it is unclear what you are trying to achieve.

There are few bicep [functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/bicep-functions) you could use to achieve what you trying to do:

```bicep
// Existing dictionary
var dict = { a: {} }

// Existing array
var array = [ 'b', 'c' ]

// Convert array to object
var arrayOfObjects = [for item in array: { '${item}': {} }]
// => arrayOfObjects = [ { b: {} }, { c: {} } ]

// Merge with existing 
var merge = concat([ dict ], arrayOfObjects)
// => merge = [ { a: {} }, { b: {} }, { c: {} } ]

// Create a single object with all elements
var newDict = reduce(merge, {}, (cur, next) => union(cur, next))
// => newDict = { a: {}, b: {}, c: {} }
```